# rust try to return a unknow length of string

Tags: rust

I am try to convert a int to binary with 000 in the front, my code is

```
fn int32_to_binerystr(i: &i32, width: &usize) -> str {
   let mut s = format!("{:032b}", i);
   let from = s.len() - width;
   let to = s.len();
   s[from..to]
}
```

it complian about :

```
   the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time
   the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `str`
   the return type of a function must have a statically known size rustcE0277
```

how to fix this?

Comment: Return a `String` with `s[from..to].into()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return a `str` (because it is not sized), nor a `&str` (if it is not static). You just need to take ownership of it with `str::to_owned` or `str::to_string`:

```rust
fn int32_to_binerystr(i: &i32, width: &usize) -> String {
   let s = format!("{:032b}", i);
   let from = s.len() - width;
   let to = s.len();
   s[from..to].to_string()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b862d54dae164e948bd67e9272834989)

Answer (score 0):

'str' is not sized, since it represents a string of unknown length.

You probably want a `String` or a `&str` instead